# css formatting for a certain content

Tags: wordpress

The thing (wordpress) is how can I make wordpress to format in a specific way (diferent from others) posts related to a certain category (it was in loop-single right?)

Does anyone have a nice link about this?

THX!

Comment: You can visit the following links: http://jonathanwold.com/tutorials/wordpress_theme/ http://themeshaper.com/2009/06/22/wordpress-themes-templates-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use WordPress' [Category Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates). For example if you have a category named news you can create template file named category-news.php (make sure you have permalinks enabled) or you can use the category ID. From there modify the contents of the category-news.php using CSS classes or IDs to display the styling you want for the category.